# TP-LINK modem can't connect to internet In automatic (PPPoE) mode

Tags: windows-7, bridge, pppoe

My TP-LINK-8901 modem does not connect to the Internet with "always on" (automatic) connection. I have to put it in bridge mode and make a connection in Windows to connect to the Internet.

Also, there is no configuration problem.

What I did:

- Reset the modem
- Update the firmware

Is there any way to solve the problem myself, e.g. through hardware or software? I can't have it repaired because the warranty already expired.

Answer (score 1):

The [Advanced Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/Troubleshooting_Guide_for_Tren.pdf) for your modem has good specific steps it suggests you follow when you have problems. Since you don't describe, in your question, the color of the modem indicator lights, I'd suggest following the entire flowchart on page 2 of the guide.

After following the guide, if the modem indicates you have connectivity, but your PC is not able to connect via wireless, you should try connecting via an Ethernet cable rather than via wireless.

If you still experience problems when connecting directly, the next step would be to replace the modem with a known working good one to verify it's working correctly.

If your ADSL light remains intermittent or off, then you will need to contact your ISP.

Comment: thanks for your answer,adsl and wlan indicator are on and internet indicator is off

Comment: pppoe password from ISP must be entered into tplink. automatic mode is for cable modems usually.